# Change node author automatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Anonymous user is able to post nodes. After posting node, user is redirected to registration. After registration, the previously submitted node should be linked with newly registered user.
I played with rules and entities but I was not able to get it work properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write a custom module (but that's me). The module needs to implement `hook_node_insert` and save the `nid` into `SESSION`. Then on `hook_user_insert` it can do the change. Untested code:

```
function foo_node_insert($node) {
  $_SESSION['mynodes'][] = $node->nid;
}

function foo_user_insert($edit, $account) {
  if (!empty($_SESSION['mynodes'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['mynodes'] as $nid) {
      $node = node_load($nid);
      $node->uid = $account->uid;
      // This saves the revision as the current user uid but that's just what we wanted.
      node_save($node);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: don't forget `unset($_SESSION['mynodes']);`

Answer (score 0):

Save the node data until after registration and post it then.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Anonymous Node Create](http://drupal.org/project/anon_nodecreate) module.

> The module allows anonymous users to create nodes. But 'anonymous' is questionable in this module. This module alters the node form for anonymous users by adding two field groups at the end before the save button.
>
> The first field group has fields that allow users to create a new account. This new account is then the author of the new node created.